# How to \protect '#' in \PackageError?

Tags: package-writing

I'm trying to write a package with a macro that's abbreviates `\PackageError`,
and I'd like in particular to use it to report messages such as
`Parameter #1 cannot be "s"`
(assuming my input validation determined the user typed something like
`\somemacro{s}`
and `\somemacro` really cannot have `s` as its first parameter).

`\#` (no protection),
`\protect\#` and
`` \protect\char`\# ``
all produce `\#` instead of `#`.
`\protect#` produces and error that reads
`ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of  .`
(that is, my error reporting system itself raises an error in that case).

So,
is it possible to print a literal `#` within `\PackageError`?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myerror}[1]{%
  \PackageError
  {Some package}
  {#1}
  {}% no extra help
}


\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\myerror{%
  \protect\#1 doesn't work,
  but \protect~ does
}

\end{document}
```

That is,
`\protect~` prints a `~`.

**--EDIT--**
Because I can't accept more than one answer,
I'd like to point out that
[antshar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661954),
[David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661956),
and
[Ulrike Fischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661950/how-to-protect-in-packageerror#comment1646664_661950)
all provide ways of printing `#` from within `\PackageError`.
As I can't think of a reason to consider one better than the others, I'll accept the answer from the user with less site reputation.

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \catcode`#=11
  \gdef\hashA{#}
\endgroup

\newcommand*{\hashB}{\csname c_hash_str\endcsname}

\newcommand*{\myerror}[1]{%
  \PackageError
  {Some package}
  {#1}
  {}% no extra help
}


\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\myerror{%
  These three forms print a hash symbol followed by "1":
  \hashA1
  \protect##1
  \hashB1
}
\end{document}
```

This correctly stops compilations and prints
`ERROR: Package Some package Error: These three forms print a hash symbol followed by "1": #1 #1 #1 .`
to the terminal.

Comment: Try `\char"0023`

Comment: This prints `\char"0023` literally

Comment: `\csname c_hash_str\endcsname1` will print `#1`.

Comment: Are you sure that users of your package will understand `#1`? I suggest “First argument cannot be s”.

Comment: @egreg well, I hadn't thought about that... I suppose it'd be best then to err on the side of caution and say something like "First argument, #1, cannot be 's' ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `#` as letter instead of active character using `\catcode` and then assign it to a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myerror}[1]{%
  \PackageError
  {Some package}
  {#1}
  {}% no extra help
}


\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\begingroup
  \catcode`#=11
  \gdef\hash{#}
\endgroup

\myerror{%
  \hash1 does work,
  and \protect~ works
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
! Package Some package Error: #1 doesn't work, but ~ does .

See the Some package package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16 }
      
?
```

from

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\myerror}[1]{%
  \PackageError
  {Some package}
  {#1}
  {}% no extra help
}


\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\myerror{%
  \protect##1 doesn't work,
  but \protect~ does
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works because `\protect` is the same as `\string` when processing `\PackageError` and the `##` has already been reduced to a single `#` when `\string` sees it.

Comment: @egreg yes I used `\protect` because that is the documented latex form, the `\protect~`  in the question also worked because it is `\string`